# How can I make my typing "stick" to box side?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, 3d

[image]

I'm using Photoshop CS6 and I'm trying to get the typing aligned with the box, kind of 3D like. I cannot seem to find the effect, I'm sure its simple.

Any help?

Answer (score 5):

1. Have your text on its own layer.
2. Convert to Smart Object (can be done on Layer Menu, Filter Menu, or Layer Panel)
3. Edit Distort

Align the angled sides first:

[image]

Then adjust for the size you want it to be on the straight sides:

[image]

---

### Alternative

1. Draw your side and text flat.
2. Select both layers and convert to smart object
3. Distort them with the text already in place

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest the alternative method, as it will allow MUCH greater customization of the font and the box in the future. You can double-click on the icon for the smart object that you create, in the payers panel, to edit its contents.  @Yadin

Comment: Google for "Vanishing point text in Photoshop" or something like that and you will find a different method. It is more flexible but with some price to pay, like having to rasterize text and lose editing ability. With a little planning you can work around that. It is definitely worth looking into.